# ElasticSearch: Operator Exception

Tags: exception, search, elasticsearch, find, operator-keyword

I have the following code that queries across _all fields which include first, last, and date of birth:

```
POST /user/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": {
               "query": "John Doe 08/11/1992",
               "operator": "and"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine but I have a special case where if the date you query is not what is matched in the record but is 1/11/1111 then it should return the user as a match. For example:

```
 POST /user/_search
    {
        "query": {
            "match": {
               "_all": {
                   "query": "John Doe 11/11/111",
                   "operator": "and"
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Should find the document even though the correct birthday is 08/11/1992. How would one go about this exception?

Comment: Did you try using `"or"` instead of `"and"`?

Comment: Yes I have tried "or" but what I am trying to accomplish is "and" logic with one exception on the date field where it could be special case 11/11/111. Using "or" would return documents that should not be returned

Answer (score 0):

Either use 'or' in the query. If this returns to many irrelevant results then try a [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and split the name and the date. Then you can match on the exact name and only on parts of the date.